# Interpret deadfish

Tags: code-golf, interpreter, deadfish

> Please participate in the ***[meta discussion about reopening this challenge](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14830/59487)*** before casting a vote.

## Introduction

This challenge was inspired by [semicolon-#](/questions/tagged/semicolon-%23).

[Deadfish](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Deadfish) is a non-Turing-complete programming language, created by Jonathan Todd Skinner. It has an accumulator register and contains 4 commands, `i`, `d`, `s`, and `o`, standing for increment, decrement, square, and output, respectively. While this seems simple enough, the original implementation has some quirks that must be present in your interpreter.

Unlike a similar challenge [here](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/16124/write-an-interactive-deadfish-interpreter), this does not require the interpreter to be interactive.

## Challenge

The challenge is to write a fully functional Deadfish interpreter, quirks included. The following requirements must be met:

- The accumulator must be more than 8 bits wide.
- When an `i` is encountered, increment the accumulator by 1.
- When a `d` is encountered, decrement the accumulator by 1.
- When an `s` is encountered, square the value of the accumulator.
- When an `o` is encountered, print the value of the accumulator along with a newline.
- When any other character is encountered, including control characters and whitespace but not a newline, print a newline.
- If and only if the accumulator equals `-1` or `256`, set the accumulator to `0`.

## Test cases

From the [esolangs article](http://esolangs.org/wiki/Deadfish):

```
iissso -> 0
diissisdo -> 288
iissisdddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddddo -> 0
```

## Rules

- Input may be accepted through STDIN or as argument(s).
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are disallowed
- This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf), so the shortest solution in bytes wins

Comment: @dylnan This one doesn't impose an interactivity requirement, however, allowing more languages to be used

Comment: True. I think people will say you should make a [meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/) about it. If they say it's a good idea and you link to the meta post on this post then people will be okay with it.

Comment: @Uriel yes it should!

Comment: [Related meta post](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/q/14830/59487).

Answer (score 0):

## [Proton](https://github.com/alexander-liao/proton), 114 bytes

```
a=0s={"i":(a=>a+1),"d":(a=>a-1),"s":(a=>a*a),"o":(a=>[print(a),a][1])}for i:input(){a=s[i](a)if a in[-1,256]{a=0}}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LclBCsMgEEbhq4grbROIhXYRsBcRFwMS@DeOOHYVPLu1NMvvvVK5cR6D/Cb@1NC7If@mu7OLThfWH@TCjSb4j1AqcjOzUAwu2n5wVdiRy6cZe5KXgDg3DkUKOaxueTxfcY6t9zESIAJJ/AU)

The fact that this even parses correctly demonstrates how weird Proton 1 is o_O